# PHP preg_replace_callback correct escaping to handle hash symbol ('#')

Tags: php, url, hashtag, backreference, preg-replace-callback

I'm doing some work with a Twitter feed and want to turn any hashtags into a clicable URL.

A hashtag is a hash symbol ('#') immediately followed by a word acting as a search tag - and contains no spaces.

An example would be ...

```
@Eutechnyx looking to form a tech group in #Shoreditch next year. Game and Web programmers get in touch. #AutoClubRev
```

There are two tags here, #Shoreditch and #AutoClubRev.

These should respectively become the following links ...

https://twitter.com/#!/search?q=%23Shoreditch
and
https://twitter.com/#!/search?q=%23AutoClubRev

I'm assuming I should be using preg_replace_callback here and not just vanilla preg_replace, as I am trying to take a backreference ($1) and change it not just display it. But of course I could be wrong. I'm not fuessed on which function to use - as long as it does the job and is relatively efficient.

Thanks,
Pete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`preg_replace`](http://fr.php.net/preg_replace) should be able to do it.

```
$test = "@Eutechnyx looking to form a tech group in #Shoreditch next year. Game and Web programmers get in touch. #AutoClubRev";

echo preg_replace('|#([\w_\d]+)|', '<a href="https://twitter.com/#!/search?q=%23\1">#\1</a>', $test);
```

Comment: Thanks RageZ, but I'm not quite there. The hash from the hash tag itself needs to be converted to the escaped character set '%23'. Surrounding this with htmlentities, etc seems to break things due to the other special characters which are actually needed for the message to make sense. So I actually need to manipulate the backreference and not just display it as is. Cheers. Pete

Comment: @PeterGross: see the edit, to be noted that the browser would have converted the character for you anyway.

Comment: Stil not quite right. The backreference \1 includes the hash tag. This doesn't replace it, it appends either %23 or another hash in front of it. I need it replacing. Thanks again for helping.

Comment: @PeterGross: give a try the hashtag is not included in `\1` since the hashtag is outside of the parenthesis.

Comment: That was it. Thanks ever so much.